# Why does opponent gain one new Lifelink Soldier card each turn?

Tags: magic-the-gathering-puzzle-quest

I'm playing in an Event (Ravina At War - Eternity) and my opponent put a Lifelink Soldier card out. Much to my surprise, each time the opponent got a turn after that, another Lifelink Soldier card was automatically added to the existing ones. Why?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the opponent's Haazda Marshal card creates lifelink soldiers when it attacks if the player has 2 or more creatures/creature reinforcements out.

[image]